# I need to populate a table when a document is created or updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express, mongoose

Im working on a MEVN CRUD app and i want to have a dashboard in which users can see, in a table, the latest changes, like "User X created Client Y" or "User X updated order Y". Ideally, every user should have their own array of items and remove items from it if necessary.

I was thinking of calling a service (after a successful post / update), that post a string containing the information to display, along with the user that performed the task, but i dont know how to handle the "every user should have their own array of items" part.

Should i add a "notifications" array to the user Schema? If so, how can i push a new notification to all users?